# How do I access raw pixel data from an HTML5 video player frame?

Tags: javascript, html, video, image-recognition

I've done some google searches on this but can't seem to find a result on how it's done. I want to experiment with image recognition at it's core, not with a library, and I'm trying to figure out how to access a frame's raw pixel data.

**How is it done?** I want to view the pixel-grid data structure of a single video frame and run formulas on that raw data, to be clear on what I'm asking. I'm pretty good with JavaScript - I'm not looking for some big tutorial on this, I'm just trying to learn how to access the image data from a video frame. For example what methods are used or what properties exist to access the pixel data.

Answer (score 2):

You can [draw the video into a canvas](http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/). Then from the canvas, use [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). It returns an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object which has a [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) property. It's a Uint8ClampedArray which contains pixel data in rgba sequence.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You draw the video frames into a html5 canvas, then get the pixels from there using `getImageData`.

The main source for trouble here is the same origin policy: It will only work if the script and the video are on the same host.

This page has some examples for direct access without a library:
http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: So, I was planning on testing video copyright infringement detection by running my image recognition of some popular copyrighted (Disney) movie against related results from YouTube - I suppose this is totally out of the question? Also, Im curious as to why Same Origin Policy would cover third party video rendering, that seems unusual.

Comment: IANAL, but the Youtube Developer TOS, section "II. *Prohibitions*" contains: "access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly authorized by YouTube;"